# Are these answers for this predicate correct?

Tags: proof-verification

I feel like I struggle a lot for these kinds of problems. I was wondering if someone could verify my answers and reasoning and possibly give some tips on how to solve these kinds of problems. Thank you.

The problem: Alice wants to prove by induction that a predicate P holds for certain nonnegative integers. She has proven that for all nonnegative integers n = 0, 1, 2, …

```
                  P(n) IMPLIES P(n+3)
```

Suppose Alice also proves that P(5) holds. Which of the following propositions can she infer?

So because Alice proved P(5) that means P(8), P(11), P(14) … holds.

- P(n) holds for all n ≥ 5

Can't infer this because we do not know, for example, if P(6) holds for the predicate.

- P(3n) holds for all n ≥ 5

Can't infer this because we not know, for example, if P(18) holds for the predicate.

- P(n) holds for n = 8, 11, 14, …

Yes, because Alice proved P(5) holds, so P(8), P(11), P(14) … holds.

P(n) does not hold for n < 5

We can't infer this statement because we don't know if P(1), P(2), P(3), and P(4) holds for the predicate or not.

- ∀n. P(3n + 5)

We can infer this because the smallest natural number is 0. And when we plug it in we get P(3(0) + 5) = P(5). And then we add three because of the statement Alice proved. So for n = 0 -> P(8). For n = 1,2,3 -> P(11), P(14), P(17).

- P(0) IMPLIES ∀n. P(3n + 2)
- P(0) IMPLIES ∀n: P(3n)

For these last two, we cannot infer either of these because for n = 0, the first statement gives P(2) and the second gives P(0). We do not know if the predicate holds for these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your very last statement is incorrect.  $P(0) \Rightarrow P(3) \Rightarrow P(6) \cdots$.

The only reason it's not true that $P(0)$ (*and* your initial assumption that Alice has proved $P(5)$) implies $P(3n+2) \forall n \in \Bbb N$ is that you still don't know $P(2)$.

Comment: Ohh I see. I assumed that 0,1,2,3, and 4 would always be numbers we are uncertain about given the initial assumption, which is why I thought that the two final statements could not be inferred. But what I had to do was assume that the statement is true along with Alice's proof of P(5). Thank you for your explanation, it really helped me!